# Ubuntu and Alt keyboard shortcut

Tags: interface, edit-mode

To do some stuff in Blender I need to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. It seems, however, that on Linux Ubuntu the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> can't be used for some actions(let's say, for example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>). However, when using right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key I than need to click the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, otherwise Blender goes to uneditable mode. I know that I could change <kbd>Alt</kbd> to something else, but I am used to it and I don't want to do so. So I rather wanna know how to prevent Blender from going into the werid mode(where I can't edit things).

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux/60977#60977

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Ubuntu uses the <kbd>alt</kbd> key as a default-key.
This worked for me.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/521423/how-can-i-disable-altclick-window-dragging

regards

Comment: Thanks! This comes as a useful information, but now I got a question - can I somehow disable it only when Blender is running?

Comment: As far as I know you can only change the shortcut globally for the system/user.

Answer (score 0):

I use Blender a lot, and in Ubuntu I can't use the alt button to select edge loops, because it is already bound as mentioned above.
As a software-specific work-around, I saved *select edge loops* as a *quick favourite*, and that gave me the usual result, with very little extra time.
I hope this helps someone!!