# Moving around the object wiith Alt key + Left Mouse Button

Tags: customization, 3d-mouse

I am new to Blender using it in Linux OS. I have tried to move the button with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. I have selected `Emulate 3D Mouse Button` from the user preference. The `select with` option is set to `Right`. But it is not working.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux/60977#60977

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Keep this settings and do not forget to **save user settings** and close