# How to use the Alt + right click in edit mode in Ubuntu 17.xx?

Tags: modeling, shortcut, linux

How can I use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd> shortcut in Ubuntu 17.xx and higher without installing additional software?

Comment: I don't remember how exactly solve is, but the key is disable ALT for system shortcuts. I thing somewhere in keyboard settings

Comment: I have removed every shortcuts in the keyboard settings and it still doesn't work. Before it was in the Window settings but it has disappeared from the System Settings panel: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux-mint

Answer (score 0):

You could use Alt + Shift + <Right Mouse Button> instead.
(This shortcut is normally not used by the system.)
This will have the same effect, except the "Shift" key will make it add the new selection to an already existing one.
So what you should do is:
1. Press A (if needed) to remove any old selections.
2. Press Alt + Shift + RMB.