# Alt+_ Shortcuts do the wrong stuff on Ubuntu

Tags: shortcut, linux

Whenever I try to linked duplicate, I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, but instead of linked duplicate I get some sort of debug menu popup. After that all blender controls have toggled to some other mysterious mode. I have to hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the view around a bit to get back to normal (a messy way, but seems to work). Same happens for any <kbd>Alt</kbd> containing shortcut like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. As you may know, all of those <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts are very useful and can speed up your process. I don't want to bother changing them to other key because:

- I am used to using <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for those tasks. It also used to work fine on Ubuntu some time ago.
- I don't want to get used to other key, as that would make me slower if I use Blender on other people's workstations(which I sometimes have to do).

P.S. I haven't changed any Blender shortcuts this far.

Comment: Probably a change in the OS use of the alt-key, and you might check there to see if you can set the system to use a different key combination.

Comment: I can't find any place in system shortcuts where Alt is being used in any of the Blender combinations or outside a combination...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the Alt + Right click in edit mode in Linux](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux)

Comment: Not quite duplicate of that since I tried using that method to solve it and it doesn't seem to be the case. Now my alt key doesn't function as the window control key. However, the problem persists. I think the problem is in Blender itself, but I can't find it's cause. It appears that Alt key sets it into some kind of weird control set where holding down middle mouse button and dragging around will change camera zoom, many shortcuts will do other stuff than expected.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis what you describe in your last comment is exactly what holding `Ctrl` + `MMB` should do, zoom the viewport. `Alt` by default does not do that.

Comment: So basically the Alt kind of "toggles" Ctrl key on virtually? Also, today I opened Blender and it seems fine. It nearly seems random to me...