# Alt+Shift+<RightMouseButton> not work for me

Tags: edges, selection-tools, shortcut

I successfully select group of edges use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightMouseButton</kbd>, but when I need highlight one more group of edges and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightMouseButton</kbd>, the old selection is deleted and the new selection is not highlighted (In theory, it action should save old selection and add new). How i can fix that?

Comment: windows, linux or mac? Are you using the blender default keyset? Any programs that could be messing with the key input?

Comment: David, linux, yes, default keyset. No third-party programm, but maybe system shortcut Alt+Shift(change keyboard language) can interrupt

Comment: that OS change keyboard language shortcut sounds *very* likely to be the issue. Try changing that and see if blender works.

Comment: David, you were right, i disabled this system shortcut and blender work normal. But it is very usable shortcut(i use it every time), maybe there is some way to save it and normal blender works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux/60977#60977

Comment: no, I alredy solved problem with mouse-modifier button <Alt>, now i have problem with Alt+Shift combination. I want save this shortcut in system and compel blender work normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced desktop shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to  <kbd>caps lock</kbd> and Blender hot key worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is not an issue with your keyboards shift key or an external program interfering with its function. (Network Mouse Applications usually interfere)

Goto User **Preferences -> Input -> 3D View -> 3D View (Global) -> Activate Select** Look for the **Shift+Alt+Select Mouse** Entry. It should have Toggle Selection and Enumerate checked. If it does not exist you have to create it or reset your whole keybindings.

Comment: Preferences set uped how you describe

Comment: Than its most likley an external issue. Like a network mouse application, or a shortcut of your desktop. Try googling shift+alt shortcut in combination with your desktop. be it windows or kde or gnome, mate, osx, etc.

Answer (score -1):

User Preferences --> Emulate 3 ButtonMouse --> Uncheck this Option

Comment: Could you elaborate on why do you think this solves the question?

Comment: I do not really know why this happens, but when i switch on - off the three button emulation, from the user preference menu, that affects the shift+alt+left click command. probably due to disabling tha alt key function.

Comment: hope that is helpful :)