# Can't Convert to Curve|Mesh using ALT+C in linux

Tags: interface, shortcut, linux

In Blender 2.79 and 2.80 on os Linux the command <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  (Convert to Curve|Mesh) does not work: pressing the keys does not cause any results.
Note that in the preferences the shortcut is correctly set.

In Windows everything is OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the OS already use this shortcut ? As a workaround you can use the menu (Object/Convert To)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcuts on the OS take precedence over those in blender.

There are two options:

- You can remap the shortcuts on linux to the <kbd>super</kbd> (<kbd>windows</kbd>) key.

  Read: [How to use the Alt + Right click in edit mode in Linux](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux/60977#60977)
- You can customize the shortcuts on blender, just know that any books or "tutorials" you watch will not match with your personalized keyboards.