# alt+rightmouse shortcut

Tags: shortcut

hope you are all well during this difficult times.
I just downloaded version 2.82a for Linux, and I was trying to follow a tutorial on how to make a photo realistic ring.
Mind you I never used Blender before,so I'm a complete novice, but since I am stuck at home as my workplace is closed, I thought I'd give it a go.

I managed to do the first ring, but as I was trying to do the second one,the guy was saying to use alt+rightmouse to select the section to extrude.
He was using an older version 2.76b, and I cannot find the same function on the newer version.

I have checked preference-keymap-select using right, saved it restart the software but is still not working.

Anyone know the right shortcut, or can point me in the right direction?

I have attached a screenshot of the point where I am stuck

Please bear with me if this is a silly question

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Hello :). This seems to be an ongoing issue with Linux https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/60961

Comment: Thanks. 
Was so focused to find a solution in Blender that I didn't even think about changing the key function in Linux.
Disabled the key on Linux, as I don't used it anyway and now the shortcut  works in Blender :)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Blender :).