# How to give one values to multiple keyframes in graph editor in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, keyframes, blenderkit

I want to select multiple keyframes and give then one value at the same time which we can do it in maya but am struggling to do that in blender.

Comment: Enable this embedded Addon: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/animation/copy_global_transform.html

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which kind of keyframes and if by multiple you mean multiple in a single channel, or multiple channels or even multiple objects I can only give you a general answer:

Like most value fields in Blender, the values of multiple keyframes on various channels can be changed by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking into the field before entering the value.

Before:
[image: multiple keyframes selected]

After:
[image: changed multiple keyframes]

If you disable the *Only Show Selected* option (the arrow symbol to the right of the menu bar), this works even with selecting multiple keyframes on different objects at the same time and even with mixed kinds of values, like *Translation* and *Scale* in the following example (only *Rotation* is a bit tricky, because Blender is then converting degrees in radians and vice versa):

Before:
[image: keyframes on two objects selected]

After:
[image: keyframes changed on both objects]

More information on the <kbd>Alt</kbd> method and how you change multiple values at once you can find in my answer here: [Video Editing: apply transformation to mupliple images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304547/video-editing-apply-transformation-to-mupliple-images/304550#304550)